# How to include two documents in the same project?

Tags: overleaf

I want to add in the same Overleaf project two papers:

1. old version of my paper
2. new version of my paper

Each of them follows a different class document.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is simply:

1. compile paper1 and upload its pdf  output to paper2
2. In project 2, add in the preamble `\usepackage{pdfpages}`
3. Then, after \begin{document}, add `\includepdf[pages={-}]{Paper1.pdf}`